# Java Generic authentication method should throws Exception or RuntimeException

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, runtimeexception, throw

I have a code like this:

```
  public void genericOperation(String username, String password) throws AuthFailedException(){
    if(username == null || password == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    AuthMethod(username,password) 
    }
```

The method AuthMethod check if username or password match, if not will it throws AuthFailedException.

Should I made it a checked exception (**AuthFailedException extends Exception**) or unchecked (**AuthFailedException extends RuntimeException**)?

I don't know if the client of this code want to recover the code in case of exceptions.

Comment: I vote checked.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Java documentation on exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html)

> Here's the bottom line guideline: If a client can reasonably be expected to recover from an exception, make it a checked exception. If a client cannot do anything to recover from the exception, make it an unchecked exception.

In the case of authentication failure, a client can be reasonably expected to take some specific action, such as reprompt for credentials - so this should be a checked exception.

Comment: the problem is that I have no idea what the client want to do in case of failure, what assumption should I choose?

Comment: You don't need to know what the client *wants* to do, but whether a client *can* do something to recover from it. Another measure to consider: Is it a *programming* error if there's an exception, or is it possible that it's a *user input* error